# Getting Assertion (-215) error while using the opencv stitcher class in vs

Tags: opencv

So many type of questions like this has been asked, and i have pass through most of them but cant still get a solution to my problem, this is the error code though: error (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

```
 bool try_use_gpu = false;
        vector<Mat>imgs; 
        Mat image, pano;
        image = imread("moscow1.jpg");
        if (image.empty())
        {

            cout << "check your input image" << endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        imgs.push_back(imread("moscow1.jpg"));
        image = imread("moscow2.jpg");
        if (image.empty())
        {
            cout << "check your input image" << endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        imgs.push_back(imread("moscow2.jpg"));

        Stitcher::Mode mode = Stitcher::PANORAMA;
        Ptr<Stitcher> stitcher = Stitcher::create(mode, try_use_gpu);
        //Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(try_use_gpu);
        Stitcher::Status status = stitcher->stitch(imgs, pano);

        if (status != Stitcher::OK)
        {
            cout << "Panorama unsuccessful" << endl;
        }

            imshow("panorama", pano);
            waitKey(0);
            imwrite("panoramaimg.jpg", pano);
}
```

am also thinking if am not implementing the stitcher class well, any help will do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images you want to stitch must have common point, for the program to use, use two different images is just not going to work if the images have no common point..